# Spark AWS Glue UI - Error: Could not find or load main class $SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS - Windows Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-spark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

Ref -
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/tree/master/utilities/Spark_UI/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-ui-history.html

I am trying to access glue spark ui locally on my windows 10 - (docker desktop) using docker container.

I have followed following steps but I get error while starting container

```
$ docker build -t glue/sparkui:latest . 


$ LOG_DIR="s3a://path_to_eventlog/"
$ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="ASIAxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
$ SESSION_TOKEN="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
$ docker run -itd -e SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS -Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=$LOG_DIR -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token=$SESSION_TOKEN -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider" -p 18080:18080 glue/sparkui:latest "/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer"

D:\glue_spark_gui_docker_file>docker logs 05c595fc8c65
Error: Could not find or load main class $SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS
```

Comment: can you run with -it instead of -itd as mentioned in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-spark-ui/ and look for the logs?

Comment: D:\glue_spark_gui_docker_file>docker run -it -e SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS -Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=$LOG_DIR -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token=$SESSION_TOKEN -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider" -p 18080:18080 glue/sparkui:latest "/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer"
Error: Could not find or load main class $SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS

Comment: same error with -it

Comment: Any resulation to this @TusharS?

Comment: Hi @AndreyBulezyuk I followed this repo.
https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/docker_spark_history_ui/blob/master/README.md

I am able to see spark ui locally. let me know if you face any issue I will help you.

Comment: I made it work locally and deployed to ECS. Had to replace "-e SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS" with "-e SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="-Dspark.hi..."

Comment: ok. are you using mac or windows ?

Answer (score 1):

same error when trying `docker on wsl` with `bash` on windows so I solved this using windows `cmd`

**1. Build image**

```
C:\Users\Avinash\Spark_UI\glue-1_0-2_0> docker build -t glue/sparkui:latest .
```

**2. set variable**

```
set LOG_DIR="s3a://path_to_eventlog/"
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="XXXXYYYY"
set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="SDFGHJHRFVBNMNBVC"
```

**3. Run container** remove `$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS` and add `%variable%` instead of `$variable`

```
docker run -itd -e SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="-Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=%LOG_DIR% -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=%AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID% -Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=%AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY%" -p 18080:18080 --name sparkui glue/spark:latest "/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer"
```

Comment: instead of Windows bash terminal use the ubuntu terminal.